# Error in File downloading file from a folder in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am encountering a problem in getting the download prompt. In the below code first am allowing the user to upload a file to compress. Once the file is compressed the user should be provided with the compressed files. But in the below code download prompt doesn't appears neither it shows any error. Please help me by correcting my code
**The view code:**

```
function CompressFile(box) {
   var file = document.getElementById('fileComp');
   if (file.value == "") {
       alert("Choose a file to upload");
       return false;
   }
   dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('file', file.files[0]);
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', '/FileUpload/Compress', true);
   xhr.send(fd);
```

}

**The controller code:**

```
 public ActionResult Compress(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var supportedType = new[] { "pdf" };
    var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Substring(1);
    var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName) ?? "";
    if (file.ContentLength > 0 && supportedType.Contains(fileExt))
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(_uploadPDF), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
        file.SaveAs(filePath);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
        string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMM_HHmmss");
        name = Server.MapPath(_fileUploadPath + name + ".pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create), PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.SetFullCompression();
        stamper.Close();
        string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name);
        return base.File(name, "application/pdf",fn);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using Ajax. You can't download a file through Ajax. You need to do a regular POST to the ActionMethod. That way the browser can send you back the file and prompt the user where he wants to save it.

Comment: What I want is whenever user clicks on compress link fileuploader should get open in modal box for ex 
function compress(box) {var box = dhtmlx.modalbox({
text: "<div>Select File <hr/><label>Filename: <input type='file' name='file' id='fileComp'></label></div><div> <input type='submit' value='Compress' />",
                    width: "300px"
                });
            }
how can i do so? If i try to use modal box than Compress action is not getting called